# Inverting a convolution with a binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics

Given the formula for $f$ in terms of $g$:
$$
f(k) = \sum_{i = 0}^n {{n}\choose{i}}g(k-i)
$$
is it possible to solve for $g(k)$ in terms of $f$ for $k\geq n$?

Comment: Is $g(k)$ defined for $k<0$?  If not then you need to specify $n \leq k$.

Comment: Thank you. For my purposes, I can set g(k) = 0 for k<0 if that helps.

Comment: If you're willing to put $f(k) = \sum_{i = 0}^k {n\choose i} g(k-i)$ (which coincides with your formula when $k\geq n$), then the answer is yes, you can solve for $g(k)$ in terms of $f$, and the solution is $g(k) = \sum_{j = 0}^k (-1)^j{j+n-1\choose j} f(k-j)$. If you only want to define $f$ for $k\geq n$ then I'm not so sure.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @NickStrehlke, I think you should write this up as an answer and OP accept it.

Comment: @vonbrand Ok, I will do so later today.